# How do i compare a string to a list of strings in PHP?

Tags: php, string, compare

Basically i have two files with strings in them separated with a new line.

What i wish to do is get the first string from the first file and compare it to ALL of the strings from the second file. Then get the second string from the first file and compare it to ALL of the strings in the second file then get the third and etc etc.

Currently i have this piece of code, but i am not sure if it is working as i wish it to be

```
$file = file_get_contents("file1.txt");
$pieces = explode("\n", trim($file));
foreach($pieces as $piece)
{
    $file2 = file_get_contents("file2.txt");
    $pieces2 = explode("\n", trim($file2));
    foreach($pieces2 as $piece2)
    {
        if($piece == $piece2)
        echo 'yes';
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Just to determine if a line in file1 also exists in file2?

Comment: I don't know PHP, but since `file2.txt` is constant, why don't you move it out of the `foreach` loop? No reason to open/parse it every time you check a new file since doing it once is sufficient, no? Also, what is the issue here? Have you tested your code?

Comment: Point taken. Though i still do not know if my code does what i need.

Comment: @dikidera - So create two files and test it out! :)

Comment: `i still do not know if my code does what i need.` - really? well, noone can help you then

Answer (score 2):

Well there is a more efficient way to achieve this. Using [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) you can find the common lines between this two files.

```
$a = file('file1.txt');
$b = file('file2.txt');
$c = array_intersect($a, $b);
```

Whatever lines which are common between the two files are found in the `$c` array. However do note that the intersection is case sensitive.

Comment: Will this do what i need? What i need is not to just compare both files if they are equal, i need to compare the first string(and so forth) to ALL of the strings in the second file.

Comment: nice answer - I'd go with this before mucking with map.

Comment: I think that in that case he could use the array_intersect_uassoc() function that compare the arrays with a callback function

Comment: @dikidera This will not compare if the files are same, but rather find the lines that exist in both files.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works correctly, if you're looking for a more elegant way I would either suggest a bash script or looking at the [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function (possibly other ones like array_walk, array_filter too.)

That being said, your code is simple and easy to follow so probably the best way to go.